# What caused this review to disappear from the low quality posts review?

Tags: support

I just noticed the following low quality post review and must say I can concur with null that it should be deleted, given the question makes no mention of problems "welding" the battery:

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/66591

However it's currently three weeks old and viewing the reviews page anonymously I can see there's only one LQP review outstanding and I know what that one is. I think a delete / undelete may cancel a review as can an edit or a "Looks OK" review but I can't see any sign of any of that on that particular answer. So I wonder what caused it to be removed from the queue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a brief time, that answer scored +1. Positively-scored posts cannot be deleted by anyone but moderators, and so are ineligible for /review - thus the review task was invalidated.

If you come across an extremely low-quality post, or an answer that does not attempt to answer the question, flag it - regardless of whether or not it's currently in review or was previously in review, it'll then be forwarded to /review and/or the mod team for handling.